# Errors when deploying kjar to jBPM/KieServer

Tags: jboss, drools, jbpm

I've been evaluating jBPM workbench and KieServer for automatically building and deploying rules, and I'm stuck on what I'm doing wrong. My goal is to have jars built and deployed to KieServer with minimal human intervention, and I've done the following:

- Started a Docker container from https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/jbpm-server-full. I'm able to create and deploy projects from within Workbench - but our workflow will also contain rules built outside of Workbench. If everything looks useful I'll just deploy the Kie Server, but I'm just in the evaluation stage.
- Created a simple rules project, with a single Data object and rule (copied directly from a successful deployment using Workbench with modified package name to prevent possible conflict) and with my settings.xml with the correct credentials and the following pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>kjar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <kie.version>7.50.0.Final</kie.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>guvnor-m2-repo</id>
            <name>JBPM Workbench Repo</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/business-central/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-model-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${kie.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${kie.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kie.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

- Built the project using `mvn clean package deploy` -
  The project gets built without error and apparently accepted by the service successfully. I can see the jar in the Docker instance, under `/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/repositories/kie/global/com/example/rules/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`
- Tried to create the container using the `http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/test` PUT API (with correct credentials) but got the following error

```
{
 "type": "FAILURE",
 "msg": "Failed to create container test with module com.example:rules:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: com.example:rules:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
 "result": null
}
```

- Tried to create a deployment unit in Workbench. I can see the package in the list and can select it, but the first time I do, I get the following error (it's barely visible in a single line text box - I've formatted it for clarity. This is a selection of a few lines out about 600)

```
{"ToSubject":"org.kie.workbench.common.screens.server.management.service.DeploymentDescriptorService:RPC","CommandType":"getProcessConfig:java.lang.String:","Qualifiers":{"^EncodedType":"java.util.ArrayList","^ObjectID":"1","^Value":[]},"ReplyTo":"org.kie.workbench.common.screens.server.management.service.DeploymentDescriptorService:RPC.getProcessConfig:java.lang.String::41:RespondTo:RPC","ErrorTo":"org.kie.workbench.common.screens.server.management.service.DeploymentDescriptorService:RPC.getProcessConfig:java.lang.String::41:Errors:RPC","AdditionalDetails":"<tt>
org.jboss.errai.bus.client.api.base.MessageDeliveryFailure: error invoking RPC endpoint public abstract org.kie.workbench.common.screens.server.management.model.ProcessConfigModule org.kie.workbench.common.screens.server.management.service.DeploymentDescriptorService.getProcessConfig(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
    at deployment.business-central.war/org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.AbstractRPCMethodCallback.invokeMethodFromMessage(AbstractRPCMethodCallback.java:75)
    at deployment.business-central.war/org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.ValueReplyRPCEndpointCallback.callback(ValueReplyRPCEndpointCallback.java:40)
    at deployment.business-central.war/org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.RemoteServiceCallback.callback(RemoteServiceCallback.java:54)
    at deployment.business-central.war/org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints$2.callback(CDIExtensionPoints.java:448)
    at deployment.business-central.war/org.jboss.errai.bus.server.DeliveryPlan.deliver(DeliveryPlan.java:47)
    at deployment.business-central.war/org.jboss.errai.bus.server.ServerMessageBusImpl.sendGlobal(ServerMessageBusImpl.java:297)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: <No Message>
    at deployment.business-central.war/org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toInputStream(IOUtils.java:1647)
    at deployment.business-central.war/org.kie.workbench.common.screens.server.management.backend.service.DeploymentDescriptorServiceCDI.getProcessConfig(DeploymentDescriptorServiceCDI.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final/org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final/org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
    at deployment.business-central.war/org.kie.workbench.common.screens.server.management.service.DeploymentDescriptorService$1790586371$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getProcessConfig(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

On selecting and trying to finish the deployment subsequently, I no longer get the above error but this time get the message `GAV 'com.example:rules:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' not found in the Maven repository. Are you sure you want to deploy it?` with the following stack trace in the logs

```
17:54:30,873 WARN [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (default task-16) Unable to resolve artifact: com.example:rules:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
17:54:31,177 WARN [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (default task-16) Unable to resolve artifact: com.example:rules:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
17:54:31,358 WARN [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (default task-16) Unable to resolve artifact: com.example:rules:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
17:54:31,360 ERROR [org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl] (default task-16) Error creating container 'baz' for module 'com.example:rules:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT': java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: com.example:rules:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:190)
at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:180)
at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl.createInternalKieContainer(KieServerImpl.java:373)
at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl.createContainer(KieServerImpl.java:286)
at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.remote.rest.common.resource.KieServerRestImpl.createContainer(KieServerRestImpl.java:155)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

So it looks like I've followed all the steps (that I know about) correctly - the jar is built, it's deployed to the `/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/repositories/kie/global/` directory, it's visible in Workbench. But it's not deployable as a container in KieServer. Does anyone have any hints on what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error in my project. I accidentally copied maven/pom.properties from another project into my META-INF directory, that had a different groupId and artifactId from the jar I was building. This caused the server to deploy the jar into the wrong /opt/jboss/.m2/repository location, so getting `GAV 'com.example:rules:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' not found in the Maven repository. Are you sure you want to deploy it?`